# I want to increase the swappiness in my windows 7

Tags: windows-7, memory, swap, virtual-memory, swappiness

as I have 60% RAM usage every time. I have already increased Virtual Memory (Increased Swap Size) but want to increase swappiness too. see my RAM usage:

[image]

Comment: post pictures of RAMMAp, this show more details about RAM usage: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2010/08/13/introduction-to-the-new-sysinternals-tool-rammap.aspx

Comment: why? just why would you want to do this atall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unused RAM is wasted RAM. There is no reason to force use of swap when your RAM is enough. 70% RAM usage is not a bad thing in a multitasking OS, it does not imply that you are low on memory as it does in a single-tasking OS (in a single process it *might*.) Windows will automatically move some of the least accessed memory to swap if you run out of RAM. Sometimes it might even preload frequently used files/programs into RAM without asking you so they load faster, which might what brings your usage up to 60-70%. Why exactly do you want to increase swappiness?

In any case, I don't think this is possible; there are ways to [decrease swappiness](https://superuser.com/questions/237137/how-to-control-ram-swap-usage) on Windows but not increase it.

Comment: *Unused RAM is wasted RAM* This isn't true. Consider the situation where you want to open a new big application when RAM is mostly taken up. Page file is not used at all. What happens? Not only do you need to move enough already open applications into the page file, but you also need to load the new application from disk. This could be improved by having the page file on a different physical drive, however I imagine that most people only have one. Having least recently used applications swapped out passively can help load new stuff quicker.

Comment: I guess my point is that it varies per use case. But unused RAM definitely isn't *always* wasted RAM.

Comment: Unused RAM *is* wasted RAM! That is actually true! You can stick pages on disk AND keep them in memory. That way, once you suddenly need lots of RAM, you can just discard those pages instantly - they're already on disk - but you do not waste RAM by being "nulled out".

Comment: Unused ram is FREE RAM. Windows is borderline stupid in terms of things it will cache, like for example entire multi gigabyte videos that make exactly zero sense to cache. You have to wait more for memory allocation if you have to evict cache, and the more data remains needlessly cached the higher the risk of random bit errors, which may even be silently committed to persistent storage, resulting in data corruption. It is actually a silly mantra by microsoft, vendor of subpar software and highly questionable business practices.

Comment: The most prominent effect of having this behavior on a high memory system is it trashes the performance of memory allocation heavy workloads, and for what? So that each time I copy a large file, it gets to 99% in an instant, then spends several minutes finishing that last 1%. Gee, that's really helpful, and it sure does help when the OS indiscriminately caches everything it touches with zero reasoning process whatsoever. Even basic SATA SSD large removes storage bottlenecks, so this feature makes zero sense on a contemporary computer.